# Tortoise SVN icon overlays not showing in shared mapped network drive folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My Tortoise SVN icons are showing up properly in folders on my local C:\ drive.  However, folders I have stored on a mapped drive are not showing any icon overlays.  I can still check-out, update, etc. on the map drive so it looks like the SVN functionality is working correctly but the icon overlays are not there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer found on [TortoiseSVN FAQ](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlonlylocal) :

> Go to the Settings -> Look and Feel -> Icon Overlays and check the
>   drive types for which you want to see overlay icons. Be aware that
>   enabling overlays for network drives will slow down not only
>   TortoiseSVN but the whole system

Answer (score 0):

Right Click, Tortoisesvn -> Settings -> Icon Overlays then select Network drives. Also has options for RAM drives removable drives, Floppy drives etc.